# Not including 'gas' or 'gasPrice' attributes in the 'options' object inside of a send() call

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

Does anyone know what the `send()` function call to a smart contract method defaults to when you don't specify `gas` or `gasPrice`? Does it automatically allocate sufficient gas and calculate the current average gasPrice? And are those attributes always optional or are there situations where including either one is mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send), both `gas` and `gas` seem to always be optional.

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't state what those will default to when not provided, but having a quick peak at the code (hopefully that's the right code path) it seems that it calls `getGasPrice` internally to get the gas price and then default the `gasPrice` to that.

```js
    // Send the actual transaction
    if (isSendTx && _.isObject(payload.params[0]) && typeof payload.params[0].gasPrice === 'undefined') {

        var getGasPrice = (new Method({
            name: 'getGasPrice',
            call: 'eth_gasPrice',
            params: 0
        })).createFunction(method.requestManager);

        getGasPrice(function (err, gasPrice) {

            if (gasPrice) {
                payload.params[0].gasPrice = gasPrice;
            }

            if (isSendTx) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    defer.eventEmitter.emit('sending', payload);
                }, 0);
            }

            sendRequest(payload, method);
        });
```

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-core-method/src/index.js)